# Creating Aion accounts with the intelliJ Maven plugins

Tags: java, blockchain, aion, oan

I'm looking to create an Aion account/address when a user creates a new account on a website. The only way I have found is via the web3 API. Is there a way to do it on the backend with using the Java plugins?

Or is there a third party API that can facilitate this?

Or what is the best practice for creating user accounts that are relatively seamless and the user does not need to know much about the interactions?

I have checked the https://docs.aion.network page but there does not seem to be any relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

There is currently no way to programmatically create an account from within a Java contract. There is the [`Blockchain.create()`](https://avm-api.aion.network/avm/blockchain#create%28java.math.BigInteger,byte[],long%29) function, but that is specifically for creating Java contracts.

There is [this repo](https://github.com/aion-kelvin/AionAccountMaker) that you can use to create a private and public key using Java.

If you're creating a frontend however, you should use something like Web3.js to create an account object:

```
async function createAccount() {
    const account = web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
    return account;
}
```

Then you could have a button in your HTML that calls `createAccount()`.

Comment: Excellent. The link above of the repository [here](https://avm-api.aion.network/avm/blockchain#create%28java.math.BigInteger,byte[],long%29)  was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to have helped. But just to reiterate: that `Blockchain.create` function cannot be used to create a user's account, i.e. a wallet. `Blockchain.create` can only ever be used to create a _contract_ account since the `byte[] data` cannont be `null`.